# Adding npm package dependencies to Angular2 project

Tags: angular, npm

Recently I have added the [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) component to an angular project that my team is working on.

I am finding it a bit painful to have to tell each team member that they need to run `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`to install the component locally.

**Is there any configuration I can add to the project so that this command is executed automatically when the project is built locally?**

Comment: What are you building with?

Comment: We aren't using any particular build tools, just angular cli to generate components and npm start to launch the app

Comment: Then go with the provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everybody needs to run this command. `npm install ngx-bootstrap` will install the package locally. If you add the `--save` flag, it will also be added to your `package.json`. Therefore, anybody who wants to use your project in the future will simply have to use `npm install` to install all dependencies defined in your project locally.

Comment: Ah thanks, I wasn't aware of this. So we just need to get everyone to do npm install each time a new package is added?

Comment: That's right. In case there are some conflicting versions, you should remove the `node_modules` folder first and then use `npm install`.

Comment: @jazza1000 please accept the answer if your problem is solved